# Tomcat 7, Coldfusion 11 .cfm handler

Tags: servlets, coldfusion, tomcat7, cfml

I have a CF11 instance running on the included Tomcat server, but when I request a `.cfm` page, all of the cfml is rendered as if it doesn't know what to do with the file type.

If I understand correctly, the `.cfm` pages need to be mapped to a servlet?  If this is the case, I can't seem to find the correct class to use in mapping the `.cfm` requests to the servlet.

In my root `web.xml`, I have

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CfmServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>[can't seem to figure out what this is supposed to be]</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CfmServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.cfm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I've seen some pages use the classes `coldfusion.CfmServlet.service` and `coldfusion.BootstrapServlet.service` but each of these return a "not found" error in the stack trace.

Am I on the right track with the servlet mapping or is this handled elsewhere?

**Edit:**

Windows 7, no additional web server.  All defaults except for a CORS filter in `[context root]/WEB-INF` (which is working) and an added context in server.xml:

```
<context
    path="/[context path]"
    docBase="[path to files]"
    WorkDir="[cfroot]\cfusion\runtime\conf\Catalina\localhost\tmp">
</context>
```

Static content displays as expected over http from the docBase directory.

Comment: Are you looking at the file via http or via file://? Is the server running?

Comment: The server is running and I'm viewing the file through http://localhost:8500/[context]/index.cfm

Comment: Windows / Linux / OSX? Apache / IIS? Is this using the default settings for the install?

Comment: If I understand you are running CF as a deployed ear file on an existing tomcat server and trying to get it to render _without_ an accompanying web server? Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not compiling to an ear (that may be the missing link in my understanding of this process) and my Tomcat server is the one that's installed with Coldfusion by default.  My understanding was that .cfm files could just be assigned to a different "handler" (class) in the config for a server or context.  Is this not an option?  And you're correct with the web server part - no external/front-end web server.  Just the Tomcat server from the CF installation.